# Angular - cannot use patchvalue for form editing

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a form where I need to be able to edit the form entry once submitted.
As you will see in the code, the form works well, each entry appears well as a line below the form.
However, I cannot manage to modify each form entry. If I split the task, it would be to send the data to the form, edit it there and then submit it again.

I think I have to use patchvalue, but I cannot manage to make it work. Any idea? This is my first Angular project and I am bit lost.

Thanks for the help!

Here is the html

```
<div class="formulario" >
<h1>Formulario</h1>

<form [formGroup]="person" (ngSubmit)="onsubmit()">
 
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <label>Introduce tu nombre</label>
    <input matInput #input id="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre (min 3 car)" formControlName="nombre">      
  </mat-form-field>

  <br/>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <label>Introduce tus apellidos</label>
    <input matInput #input id="apellidos" type="text" placeholder="Apellidos (min 3 car)" formControlName="apellidos"/>
  </mat-form-field>
  <br/>
<button type = "submit" > Enviar tus datos</button>

    </form>
  </div>



<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Posición</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
        <th> Modificar</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let persona of personas; let i = index">
            <td>{{i}}</td>
            <td>{{persona.nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{persona.apellidos}}</td>
            <td> <button mat-flat-button (click)="edititem(i)" >Modificar</button></td>
      <td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my ts :

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Persona } from 'src/app/components/formulario/persona';
import { FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormGroupDirective, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-formulario',
  templateUrl: './formulario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./formulario.component.css']
})

export class FormularioComponent implements OnInit {
    person: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
    personas : Persona[] = [];

    constructor(){
        this.person = new FormGroup({
            nombre : new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
            apellidos : new FormControl("", [Validators.required,  Validators.minLength(3)]),
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() : void{
        }

    onsubmit() {
        let persona = new Persona();

        persona.nombre = this.person.value.nombre;
        persona.apellidos = this.person.value.apellidos;

        this.personas.push(persona);
        this.person.reset();
    }

    edititem(i : number) : void {
            this.person.patchValue({i})
            this.person.get('nombre')?.setValue(this.person.value.nombre)
            this.person.get('apellidos')?.setValue(this.personas[i])

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass, futhermore the index the "whole" persona to your edititem function

```
<button mat-flat-button (click)="edititem(i,persona )" >
```

Then use a variable "indexEdited" -at last equal to -1, and change your function update like

```
indexEdited:number=-1;
edititem(i:number,persona:Persona) : void {
     this.person.patchValue(persona)
     this.indexEdited=i;  //<--store the index selected
}
```

Now in submit you check if indexEdited is equal to -1 to not add else change the array

```
onsubmit() {
    let persona = new Persona();

    persona.nombre = this.person.value.nombre;
    persona.apellidos = this.person.value.apellidos;

    //check if you're "editing" or not
    if (this.indexEdited==-1)
       this.personas.push(persona);
    else
       this.personas[this.indexEdited]=persona;

    this.indexEdited=-1;  //<--you say that you're not editing
    this.person.reset();
}
```

NOTE: if your class "Persona" only has properties, use an interface instead of a class. Imagine some like

```
export interface Persona{
   nombre:string;
   apellidos:string;
}
```

And you can use in onSubmit some like

```
const persona:Persona={nombre:this.person.value.nombre,
                      apellidos:this.person.value.nombre
                     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Eliseo for your detailled answer, this helped me a lot! 
I was trying for so long and could not manage to fix it! You are right, it was necessary to link it with the submit button as well to avoid another issue.