# Angular - avoid UUID assignation when updating a form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am working on my final project where I have to create a form with a user ID automatically assigned when I create a user. The user can be updated or removed at all time.

The issue I have now is that every time I update my form (see [Angular - cannot use patchvalue for form editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72365023/angular-cannot-use-patchvalue-for-form-editing) for more context as I used the same structure) the user id I assigned is updating.

I decided to use UUID as it was an easy way to avoid duplicates. However, every time I update the form, it resets the UUID.

My idea was to assign the current value to a new variable, so I could just say that if it does not change, we would need to use this. Sadly it does not work. I also tried other options such as assigning a default UUID and check if it was not this one, but it did not work either.

I am only including a part of the TS file around that issue as the rest is working fine, but feel free to ask if you need more.

onsubmit() {

```
    let socio = new Socio();

    socio.nombre = this.member.value.nombre;

    socio.socioid = UUID.UUID();
    let actualsocid = socio.socioid;

    if (this.indexEdited==-1)
    socio.socioid= actualsocid;
    else 
    socio.socioid = UUID.UUID();


    if (this.indexEdited==-1)
    this.socios.push(socio);
    else
    this.socios[this.indexEdited]=socio;

 this.indexEdited=-1;  
 this.member.reset();

}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why do you create all that in the onSubmit handler? Use the angular controller to keep all that and then call a create function in the handler. Seperating UI Code from buissness logic will only benefit you in the long run.

Comment: I have tried also that. However, it still does not solve the issue, the ID is updated everytime.